# keep getting implicit declaration errors

Tags: c, linux, shell

Error

```
In function ‘main’:
assignment.c:46:14: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fork’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   46 |     int pid= fork();
      |              ^~~~
assignment.c:49:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘execvp’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   49 |         execvp(command[0],command);
      |         ^~~~~~
assignment.c:54:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘wait’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   54 |         wait(NULL);
      |         ^~~~
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    
    char line[200];
    char* command[100];
    char progpath[20];
    int argc;

while(1){

printf("Enter command and press ctrl + D or type Exit to terminate program \n ");                   

        if(!fgets(line, 200, stdin)){  
        break;                                
    }
    size_t length = strlen(line);
    if(line[length - 1] == '\n')
    line[length - 1] = '\0';
    if(strcmp(line, "exit")==0){            
        break;
    }

    char *token;                  
    token = strtok(line," ");
    int i=0;
    while(token!=NULL){
        command[i]=token;
        token = strtok(NULL," ");
        i++;
    }
     command[i]=NULL;                    

    argc=i;                          
    for(i=0; i<argc; i++){
        printf("%s\n", command[i]);      
    }
    for(i=0; i<strlen(progpath); i++){    
        if(progpath[i]=='\n'){
            progpath[i]='\0';
        }
    }

    int pid= fork();           

    if(pid==0){              
        execvp(command[0],command);
        fprintf(stderr, "Child process could not do execvp\n");

    }
    else{                  
        wait(NULL);
        printf("Child exited\n");
    }

}
}
```

pls help me to solve this problem as soon as possible

Comment: You need to include headers where the mentioned functions are declared.

Comment: hint: `#include <unistd.h>`

Comment: Do `man fork`, `man execvp` and `man 2 wait` and read the SYNOPSIS. The union of those headers is what you need.

Comment: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to add these preprocessor directives:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>    // fork, execvp
#include <sys/wait.h>  // wait
```

Also, `fork()` does not return an `int` but a `pid_t`. Use the correct types.

Comment: I didn't see what `sys/types.h` is needed for. Please add that info too.